# Traceback (most recent call last):

Tags: mesh, add-on

I am currently learning Blender on Ubuntu 18.04 for openFOAM meshing. I was going through a tutorial today and the error in the image came up when I clicked on "Build" in the swiftBlock tab. Not entirely sure how to proceed.[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

While I do not know a lot about this "OpenFOAM", it seems like it is a language or library designed to run on blender in order to generate meshes. According to the error, it says `ZeroDivisionError: Float division by zero`.

This is Python's (language blender is coded in) way of telling you that you are trying to divide a number by 0. I recommend checking your OpenFOAM code for instances where you do such a thing. The error also points you to the line of code that threw the error, so you might want to look at that closely.

Answer (score 0):

So I gave it another go making the object I had to, and this time it worked. So I can only assume that last time my object was **either a not fully closed(sealed) domain, or I had a vertex or edge selected when I clicked on "Initalize blocking" in the swiftBlock tab**. 
Which is why it was throing the `Division by zero` error.

openFOAM is an opensource cfd software, however it is easier to make the renderings in Blender or any other rendering software and then try to run your simulation in openFOAM.